# Can't change order of menu items in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I have a Joomla 3 site with several menus. When I make changes to the order of these in the backend, the order is not reflected in the front end.

I have cleared / purged the cache and tried to run this fix

```
UPDATE `database-name`.`jxx_menu` SET `ordering` = '0'
```

which wouldn't work because I am running 3.3 and there is no column 'ordering' in that table.

Any ideas what's wrong please?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to order the menu items? Using the drag-n-drop feature that is built in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to click the two opposing triangles, at the top of the ordering column  (far left), in oder to "activate" the menu ordering.

Then you can click and grap a menu and drop it into the right place in your menu structure.

You definitely don't need any "fix" to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **Rebuild** in the menu manager. If you change the order there, it must be reflected in the frontend.